# C++ com C#, é possível?

Tags: c#, c++, interoperabilidade

Tenho um projeto em C++ usando recursos visuais nele usando wxWidgets.

Estava querendo transferir o visual do projeto pra C#.

É possível ter a programação das funções em C++, porém a programação do visual toda em C#, ou seja, os botões chamarem as funções em C++?

Comment: Isso da para fazer, se você enviar todas as ações do formulário por Web Service, mas, eu não aconselho fazer isso.
Talvez, tenha alguém ai que conheça outra alternativa, mas eu acho que não exista, por que o C++ usa um compilador e C# usa outro.

Comment: isso seria uma gambiarra das bravas e sem necessidade, se vai migar para uma linguagem mais parruda, não seria muito mais facil adaptar a sintaxe das funções para C#, a lógica continuara a mesma.

Comment: Eu diria pra ficar no C++.

Comment: O problema é que tenho mais de 5 mil linhas prontas, gostaria de colocar um visual ao programa, sem precisar da extensao do wx....

Comment: Depende um pouco de como está o seu código, mas uma opção é transformar a parte do C++ em uma DLL, que você pode usar no programa escrito em C# (que ficaria a cargo dos elementos de interface e respectivos *event handlers*).

Comment: Entendi, você poderia me explicar melhor como eu faço isso??

Comment: @Estevão Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 8):

É possível usando o [C++/CLI](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI). Esta é uma versão gerenciada do C++ que é usada com o .NET.

Não vou entrar em muitos detalhes porque provavelmente você não vai querer usá-lo. Na verdade ele só costuma ser usado como cola entre aplicações C# e C++ nativo. Ou seja, você vai fazer a parte principal da aplicação em C#, e usará o tal do C++/CLI para dar acesso ao C# às funções escritas em C++ nativo.

Claro que é possível usar o código em C++ no C++/CLI. Ele não é o C++ puro mas é bem parecido em quase tudo. Mas é quase certo que exija algumas adaptações.

Evite fazer isto, mas está aí uma possibilidade. Se vai passar para o C# pense bem se existe alguma razão para deixar uma parte em C++, normalmente não precisa, você só vai criar complicações sem ter nenhum benefício.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).