# Comunicação de programa em C++ com um em C#

Tags: c#, c++

Bom pessoal, eu estou passando por um probleminha, eu tenho uma aplicação em c++ e tenho que fazer com que a saída dela seja lida por um programa feito em C#. gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de fazer isso?, queria que tivesse uma comunicação entre elas.

Comment: Olá seja bem vindo !  tente acrescentar no enunciado mais alguns detalhes de sua aplicação em c++ , você pode começar pelo trecho de código , temos que entender como e feita a "saida"  do seu programa. A "saída" seria um texto em uma aplicação console ?

Comment: Inicialmente a saída dela é feita por console, mas queria que fosse de outra forma, não tenho muita base de c++.

Comment: Que tal salvar a saída em um arquivo de texto ( .txt ) ? assim você pode realizar a leitura em um programa no C# , eu acredito que seria a forma mais fácil.

Comment: mas teria como eu fazer com que meu programa em c# verificasse se existe conteúdo naquele txt?

Comment: O meu real problema é o seguinte, eu estou tentando desenvolver uma aplicação que através de uma câmera identifique a placa de um veículo e mande essa resposta pro meu programa feito em c#, eu queria fazer tudo em c# mas não consegui achar nenhuma ferramente que me auxiliasse a desenvolver a parte de identificação da placa nessa linguagem, somente em c++.

Comment: Mas o OpenCV por exemplo é possível integrar com C#

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/69742/101

Comment: OpenCV em C#: http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "eu tenho uma aplicação em c++ e tenho que fazer com que a saída dela
>   seja lida por um programa feito em C#. gostaria de saber se existe
>   alguma forma de fazer isso?"

**Sim**, a minha sugestão e que você faço o armazenamento da informação de saída em um `arquivo.txt`.

Os exemplos a seguir são aplicações feita em `Console`.

O primeiro exemplo e um programa em `c++` que cria e escreve as informações da placa em um arquivo `.txt`

**Programa C++**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main () {
  ofstream myfile;
  myfile.open ("Placa_Veiculo.txt");
  myfile << "ABC-1234";
  myfile.close();
  return 0;
}
```

O segundo irá realizar a leitura do arquivo de texto. onde assim em seu programa `c#` irá realizar o tratamento desejada para a informação da placa.

**Programa em C#**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {   // abrir arquivo de texto usando stream reader.
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\usuario_do_mal\Desktop\Pasta do meu Projeto C++\Placa_Veiculo.txt"))
                {
                    // Ler arquivo e armazenar a informação da placa
                    String Leitura_Arquivo = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    string Placa = Leitura_Arquivo;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Erro  :");
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
```

Lembre-se de utilizar o `namespace` [System.IO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.io(v=vs.110).aspx).

**Obs** : Note que um exemplo bem simplificado, e foi feito para atender a necessidade de tudo o que foi dito ate o momento.

Você pode consultar as **fontes** clicando  [aqui](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/) e [aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/db5x7c0d(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

O que você necessita é realizar interop entre as aplicações.
Se você tem a assinatura do módulo em C/C++, você pode usar esta ferramenta que faz a montagem de interfaceamento de tipos automaticamente:
[PInvoke Interop Assistant](http://clrinterop.codeplex.com/releases/view/14120)