# É possível interagir um código C# com código externo ao .NET?

Tags: c#, c, .net, windows, clr

Como fazer para chamar código escrito em outra linguagem que não faz parte do .NET, por exemplo a linguagem C?

Como se dá essa interação?

Como chamar funções nativas do Windows?

Comment: Estou fazendo esta pergunta porque entendi errado a versão original de https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/227301/101 e respondi isso, para não perder o conteúdo que acho ser útil estou postando aqui. Se tiver outras dúvidas poste uma nova pergunta.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sim. Na verdade boa parte do .NET interopera com a [Win32](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34953/101) ou com a API de outros sistemas operacionais que são fornecidas em C. Então é possível você interoperar também. Geralmente estamos falando de trabalhar com código não gerenciado. Tudo o que ocorre nele não tem controle do [CLR](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51281/101) e de forma geral as alocações de memória devem ser controladas por este código não tendo intervenção do [*garbage collector*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/110854/101), por isso é bem mais arriscado. Mas existe toda uma infraestrutura para suportar a comunicação de forma simplificada entre a parte gerenciada e não gerenciada.

Na verdade é possível interagir com boa parte dos códigos existentes em qualquer linguagem desde que esses códigos atendam certos requisitos, que possua [ABI](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/187944/101) compatível. Qualquer código em C interage bem. C foi pensada nisso e o sistema operacional, seja Windows, Linux e a maioria dos outros são escritos ou pelo menos possui sua API básica em C. É muito fácil chamar código em C a partir do .NET e até fazer algumas partes do código .NET poderem ser chamadas em C. Um exemplo é o SQLite que é escrito todo em C e muita gente o usa como banco de dados embarcado na aplicação .NET.

É possível chamar código em C++ também. E não estou nem falando das partes compatíveis com C, falo das classes também. Existe o [C++/CLI](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/69742/101) no .NET que é um C++ gerenciado que interage bem com o C++ não gerenciado. Particularmente se eu puder evitar eu prefiro, acho a interação com C bem mais fácil. Tanto é complicado que o UWP que nativamente é escrito em C++ usa uma interação com .NET um pouco diferente ([CX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CX)).

O código não gerenciado deve ficar segregado em outra DLL já que são binários muito diferentes. Em [.NET Native](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30793/101) não precisa. Então precisa carregar a DLL e criar [assinaturas para as funções](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101) e estruturas disponíveis no código não gerenciado para que o compilador do C# ou outra linguagem do .NET reconhece aquela função e detecte erros. Algo assim:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class Program {
    [DllImport("teste.DLL", EntryPoint="print")]
    static extern void print(string message);

    public static void Main(string[] args) => print("Chamando C");
}
```

Em C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void print(const char *message) {
    printf("%s", message);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Interop/CallFunction.cs)